# C on linux: using fclose() on Filepointers made from Socket descriptors

Tags: c, linux, sockets, fclose

I have to write a simple command-line client/server thingy for school and our teacher told us that using fdopen on Sockets is the easy way to go. A protocol is given that defines simple requests and responses only marked by EOF (so not within the request itself but the FIN flag will have to do).

Now my problem is that in order to get a response in the client I have to close the writing direction.
For this I'm using fclose()
Leaving out the details what I'm doing (skipping all the error handling and unrelated stuff)is pretty much:

```
sdr = socket(..); 
sdw=dup(sdr); 
writepointer = fdopen(sdw,"w");
readpointer = fdopen(sdr,"r");
send_message(writepointer); 
fclose (writepointer);
```

Now I would expect flcose() (which successfully return 0 btw) to send EOF, fflush(), close the pointer and close the underlying socket descriptor resulting in a fin flag being sent from the client to the server.

Now when I single step through the program and simultaniously look at tcpdump I see the request being sent (and ack'ed  by the server) when I call fclose() but no FIN flag. 
This of course results in the Server not seeing that the request is done and my client getting very bored when trying to read a response later on.

I don't find many people using file pointers for tcp transfers here so a search for this didn't yield a whole lot.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to cause a shutdown of a TCP socket and you are doing neither of them. One of them is to call `shutdown`. You are not doing that. The other is to close the last descriptor that references the connection. You are not doing that.

Do one of those two things.

Your expectation that this will trigger a shutdown is unreasonable. You still have a socket open to the connection that can be used to both read from it and write to it. So it would be quite surprising if a TCP protocol shutdown was triggered.

Comment: Now that's the thing: fclose() is supposed to do close() on the descriptor the filepointer was made from for you. Trusting in what the lecturer told us I even establish the connection in a another function only filling buffers for the filepointers without explicitly returning the socket in any way. From the fclose man-page: `The fclose() function flushes the stream pointed to by stream (writing any buffered output data
       using fflush(3)) and closes the underlying file descriptor.`

Comment: @gotjazz84 : in this case, `and closes the underlying file descriptor` should be read as: "drops its reference to the file descriptor",  the other fopen()d FILE still has a reference to it.

Comment: @joop which is why I use dup.

Comment: A file *descriptor* is a sort of reference to an *open file description*. Closing the former only closes the latter if it's the last reference

Comment: From the dupx() manual page: `After a successful return from one of these system calls, the old and new file descriptors may be used interchangeably.  They refer to the same
       open file description`   "File description" := one entry in the "sytem file table"

Comment: You guys are right. While fclose correctly closes one descriptor I had to shutdown the &quot;writing end&quot; of the dup() &#39;ed one too to get the client to send a fin

Comment: @gotjazz84 Note that when you `dup` a descriptor, you get two descriptors that both reference precisely the same thing. So that one is a "writing end" is just how you happen to use them. The implementation considers them interchangeable since they both reference the same entry.

Comment: @David Schwartz: I only meant to clarify which parameter on which descriptor I called shutdown. Because on the one I made the fclosed Filepointer on that doesn't do anything anymore of course